# How to whitelist (Windows Firewall) a program using the Java runtime?

Tags: windows-7, java, firewall, windows-firewall

I am using Windows Firewall on a Windows 7 laptop to block outgoing connections by default. I want to allow SurveyCTO, which requires Java, to sync with a remote server. Even with "Allow" rules for the SurveyCTO_Client.exe executable and java.exe, the client program fails to sync, with the following error.

> **Could not fetch source forms...**
>
> Reason: Unable to fetch form list: Unexpected java.net.SocketException

How can I permit the connection?

I'm new to this aggressive firewalling business. In general, is there a good way to determine which connections need to be allowed?

Comment: Have you tried asking them what ports they use? https://www.surveycto.com/support/login.html

Comment: I have now! But isn't it better to allow just the program rather than opening up a whole port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SurveyCTO uses `javaw.exe` rather than `java.exe`, so this is the program that needs to be allowed outgoing access in Windows Firewall.

I contacted SurveyCTO support to find out. Furthermore, SurveyCTO uses the standard HTTP ports 443 and 80, so creating an allow rule for the program allows keeping those ports blocked.

`javaw.exe` is the Java runtime that cannot access the console, and it is often used to launch GUI apps.